# What does the Python error "name 'self' is not defined" mean?

Tags: python

I can't figure out what's wrong with this [very simple snippet](http://ideone.com/wuXCV):

```
class A(object):
        def printme(self):
                print "A"

        self.printme()

a = A()
```

Error output:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):   File "prog.py", line 1, in
 <module>
     class A(object):   File "prog.py", line 5, in A
     self.printme() NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The following should explain the problem. Maybe you will want to try this?

```
class A(object):
    def printme(self):
        print "A"
a = A()
a.printme()
```

The name `self` is only defined inside methods that explicitly declare a parameter called `self`.  It is not defined at the class scope.

The class scope is executed only once, at class definition time.  "Calling" the class with `A()` calls it's constructor `__init__()` instead.  So maybe you actually want this:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.printme()
    def printme(self):
        print "A"
a = A()
```

Comment: Sven- I know that works, but what I'm trying to do is access the method within the class body. Is self not callable within a class instance?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: @Yarin: What do you mean by "callable", and what by "within a class instance"?  There is no instance of the class at definition time -- the class isn't even defined yet, so there can't be an instance.

Comment: @Sven- ok that makes sense- my call belongs within the __init__ body... little rusty this morning.

Answer (score 3):

If you're intending for the function to run each time an instance of the class is created, try this:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.printme()

    def printme(self):
        print "A"

a = A()
```

Comment: Thanks- what i was looking for- Sven just got there first

Answer (score 2):

It's exactly what it says: `self` is not defined when you call `self.printme()`. `self` isn't magically defined for you in Python; it only works inside a method which has an argument named `self`. If it helps, try replacing the word `self` with something else, say `foo`, throughout your program (because there is really nothing special about `self` as an identifier).

Comment: You still define __init__ with self as an argument.

Comment: Thomas- yeah i just figured it out- had already deleted the comment- thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you want to print something when you instantiate the object use:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
            self.printme()

    def printme(self):
            print "A"

a = A()
```